# How do I define the constructor?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Rec{
  public void txtMod(){
    File fileName = new File ("C:\\work\\imput.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(fileName));
    ...
  }
}
```

`new InputStreamReader(fileName)` gets underlined with the following error: '*The constructor InputStreamReader(File) is undefined*'. How do I define it? Doesn't `new` define it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That isn't a valid argument for constructing an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html). You need to create the InputStream and pass that to the InputStreamReader.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (
                        new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(fileName)));
```

However, the best way to do this is to use a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).

```
Reader in = new FileReader(fileName)
```

Comment: would you prefer `FileReader` or `BufferedReader` for reading a file?? ....considering `charset` also has to be kept in mind??

Answer (score 2):

You messed up your terms a bit. `new` *instantiates* a class. It doesn't define anything.

Your error is caused by the fact that there is no constructor for `InputStreamReader` that takes a `String`. `FileInputStream` does, however, and the resulting stream can then be passed to a `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 1):

InputStreamReader does not take a File in the constructor. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html. What you want is probably FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Under Constructor Summary, there is no constructor that takes a parameter File.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

You may want to use

```
new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( fileName ) )
```